# How to add only unrefered node of a content type in an entity reference field of another content type

Tags: nodes

There are 2(two) Node types

1. A
2. B

**A** has a node reference field to node type **B**.

If a node *x* of **A** type used a node *y* of **B** type as a node-reference then next time node *z* of **A** type will not use the node *y* of **B** type as a node-reference because *x* is already used as node-reference.

Comment: Did you already try the [Entityreference unique](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_unique) or [Field validation](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_validation) module?

Comment: No, but I think [Entityreference unique](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_unique) will be perfect though I've not found the recommended version.

Comment: @johirpro what do you mean by recommended version? It does not have a *stable* release yet, but rc means release candidate - maintainer thinks it's ready and all he needs is some brave people who will start using it and confirm it's ready :) By using it and reporting everything you didn't found to work as expected, you help maintainers to help you.

Comment: Thanks! @Mołot to explain about the meaning of **rc**. I'll use the _stable_ release.

Comment: The Git repository is indeed a bit messy, there is also an issue (more than a year old) of applying Drupal's coding standards.. I would use the rc version.

Answer (score 1):

The [Entityreference unique](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_unique) sounds what you're looking:

> This modules adds a checkbox to an entity reference instance to enable a check for unique multiple entity reference fields. With this option enabled it is not possible to add one and the same entity to a multiple entity reference field.